# why does it show "No installed app with label 'learning_logs' " when i try to migrate while I have it in the list of installed apps in settings.py?

Tags: python, django, django-models

i have made an app for a project in django and wrote a class in models.py . i have also included the name of app in the list of INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py . after it, when i try to migrate this change, it says "No installed app with label 'learning_logs'"

the relevent screenshots:
[image: INSTALLED_APPS]
[image: The full directory of project]
[image: results of terminal]
[image: I tried this as per suggestions.problem not gone]

please help.

i tried to do the same thing many times and it didn't work. i expected to get a success message but it showed other( as seen in screenshot)

Comment: Can you add the `apps.py` from learning_logs? The label should be defined there

Comment: Are you in correct directory in your CMD?

Comment: Can you try changing `learning_logs` in INSTALLED_APPS to `learning_logs.apps.Learning_logsConfig`?

Comment: @obrunt I tried renaming it to that. it still does not work :(

Comment: @AnkitTiwari Yes, I am in the right directory.(as far as I know as beginner )

Comment: Hello @theunbugger, How many `learning_log` folders do you see or you've created if it's 2 then you're in wrong directory according to you CMD screen shot.

Comment: hey @AnkitTiwari, actually i have created only one folder named learning_log. the rest of folders are due to the creation of virtual environment, start project and app start. after starting project , I have changed the directory as required, otherwise I wont be able to make app.

Comment: Have you tried running `makemigrations` without specifying the learning_logs app?

Comment: Hello @theunbugger check your `apps.py` does it configured correctly if it is then try to restart your terminal

Comment: sorry, I finally found that there was a capitalization error in models.py  it is solved now. Thanks